# regular expression to remove all non-keyboard characters

Tags: regex, perl, latex

I have read [Remove Non-Alphanumeric Characters from a String](http://mundeep.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string/) and do not believe it solves my problem.

I have a Perl script containing a single regular expression. This is designed to replace with a space every non-keyboard character in a text file.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
#   Delete any character (replace it with a space) that is not a visible keyboard
#   character.
if($#ARGV!=0) {
        print "usage: pass a *single* filename as argument. Filename is a text file ...\n";
        exit;
}
$infile=$ARGV[0];
#print "\$infile is $infile\n";
open(SOMEFILE, $infile)||die("can't open $infile for reading");
while(<SOMEFILE>) {
    $oldStr = $_;
    $newStr=$oldStr;
    $newStr=~s/[^\w\s`~!@#\$\%^&*()-_=+[\]{}\\|;:'",<.>\/?àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôûÿøÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜÂÊÎÔÛŸØçÇß¿“”‘’æÆ£¢]/ /g;
    print "$newStr";
}
close SOMEFILE;
exit;
```

This should remove *all* funny invisible characters. But it does not appear to work. Example file:

```
$ hex 1bad
0000  43 61 74 68 65 72 69 6e  65 c2 a0 0a              Catherin e...
```

The file `1bad` contains text copied and pasted from an email.  This text, when inserted into a "verbatim" environment in a LaTeX file, returns an error.

Why does this regular expression not work?

Comment: What do you class as a keyboard character? What keyboard?

Comment: maybe it's not processing unicode characters correctly? an alternative to a regex would be to iterate over all the (unicode) characters, and check if their decimal value is within the range of printable characters.

Comment: I mean my Macbook Pro keyboard. I list all the characters in the regular expression in the perl script on the website: $newStr=~s/[^\w\s`~!@#\$\%^&*()-_=+[\]{}\\|;:'",<.>\/?àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôûÿøÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜÂÊÎÔÛŸØçÇß¿“”‘’æÆ£¢]/ /g;

Comment: But that title do you mean this article? http://mundeep.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string/

Comment: Yes, that's the article I meant.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your suggestion. Why would a regex in a perl script run in the bash shell on a Mac, not process unicode characters correctly? I would think that my negated class regex would simply remove all characters that are not in the characters listed in that regex.

Comment: @JacobWegelin: I'd think so too..I'm just trying to think outside of the box. PHP, for example, is notoriously bad at handling multi-byte characters. Not sure about perl.

Comment: Hard to guess since you didn't post any code, but I suspect the encoding of the file does not match what you told Perl it is. I also suspect you didn't properly decode your input and your output.

Comment: And what error does LaTeX emit?

Answer (score 4):

Your filter could be much simpler written:

```
perl -C -Mutf8 -lpe's/[^\w\s`~!@#\$\%^&*()-_=+[\]{}\\|;:\x{27}",<.>\/?àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôûÿøÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜÂÊÎÔÛŸØçÇß¿“”‘’æÆ£¢]/ /g' 1bad
```

It works as designed, the `"\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}"` character at the end of the word in the example file matches `\s`, so it is *not* substituted. You need to be break that character class apart to be more specific. In Perl 5.16, `\s` matches the following characters:

```
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
U+000A LINE FEED
U+000C FORM FEED
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
U+0020 SPACE
U+0085 NEXT LINE
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean removing any punctuation right?  If so try:

```
$string =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
```

Comment: that's not what i took away from this question

Comment: This should be of interest to people who (1) use LaTeX and (2) copy text from emails into LaTeX documents. Repeatedly when I try to include text from an email into a LaTeX document, I get an error saying there is an unknown "u8" character. The only way that I can include the text is by cleaning it by hand using an editor. A simple regular expression with a negated character class should solve this. I am mystified as to why the regex that I provide on the website, does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by making it a LaTeX problem, not a perl regex problem.

I gave up on pdflatex and use xelatex instead. The former runs faster but "chokes" on unfamiliar characters, even invisible ones. The latter runs slower but it seems not to mind any character. It simply doesn't render a character that it doesn't know how to deal with. For instance, my current LaTeX code renders polytonic Greek just fine (the characters in which ancient Greek authors are now written) but it leaves a blank for any Chinese character.